# What is different between the two methods of generating cluster primary keys?

Tags: sql-server

I have a Table to make a Clustered Primary Key.

```
  CREATE TABLE dbo.SampleTable
  (
   C1 INT NOT NULL,
   C2 INT NOT NULL )
```

First Way is making Primary Key index with Clustered index.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SampleTable ADD CONSTRAINT IDX_SampleTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (C1, C2)
```

Second Way is `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX` after `ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED` about same columns.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SampleTable ADD CONSTRAINT IDX_SampleTable PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (C1, C2)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_SampleTable2 ON dbo.SampleTable (C1 ,C2)    -- Can not create Same Name With above Constraint Name
```

Is there a difference in performance from the above two methods?
Is there a way do not recommend using it?

Comment: What are you actually asking here: "What is the difference between A Clustered and NonClustered Index?" or "What is better, using a Clustered Primary Key, or using a Nonclustered primary key and then creating a clustered index on the primary key?"

Comment: @Larnu Second One. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. By specifying `CLUSTERED`, you instruct the database to store the data in a certain way. Basically, it enforces that subsequent indexes are stored on subsequent data blocks on the hard drive.

By creating a clustered primary key as in your first statement, all the data in the table will always have unique values in `C1, C2` and the data is always stored in subsequent data blocks.

In the second example, you do NOT enforce this `CLUSTERED` behaviour through the primary key, but through a separate index. Though the effects are the same now, you might choose to remove (or temporarily disable) the index and then the data would no longer be guaranteed to get stored in a `CLUSTERED` fashion.

Bottom line: In practice these two statements are the same now, but might make a difference in the future because the `CLUSTERED` property is not integrated in the PK, but in a separate index.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Nonclustered Primary Key and then creating a Clustered index on the columns  within the Primary key is not a good idea. Effectively you'll create 2 indexes on the columns (`C1` and `C2` in this case), however, it's very unlikely the nonclustered index will ever be used. This is because the Clustered Index is very likely going to be the first choice for the RDBMS, as the pages will be in the order of the Clustered Index. Also, when using a non-clustered index the data engine will still need to refer to the Clustered Index afterwards, to find out the exact location of the row (in the pages).

If you do want a clustered index on your Primary Key(s) then create the key as a Clustered Primary Key. *This is not to say that your Primary Key should always be Clustered, but that is a very different subject.*

Answer (score 0):

This depends from your datas:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-2017

> Clustered indexes sort and store the data rows in the table or view
>   based on their key values. These are the columns included in the index
>   definition. There can be only one clustered index per table, because
>   the data rows themselves can be stored in only one order.

So the clustered key influence the format of your physical data structure.